# Safari Popup Does Not Open - Not Returning Object when Executing window.open()

Tags: javascript, safari, popup, popupwindow

Given the method:

```
function openInNewWindow(url) {
    var win = window.open(url, "title");
    win.focus();
}
```

In Safari the object "win" is "undefined" after "window.open" and the new window is not opened.

Any ideas why this happens?

Comment: How does `openIn...` get called

Comment: It is called when a user clicks a link.

Answer (score 1):

Safari's default popup blocker is more aggressive than other browsers. The method should look like this.

```
function openInNewWindow(url) {
    var win = window.open(url, "title");
    if (!win) {
        alert("Please disable your popup blocker.");
    } else {
        win.focus();
    }
}
```